# Como imprimir desde angularjs

Tags: angularjs

soy nuevo en angular y quisiera saber como le puedo hacer para programar un boton que me imprima lo que esta en pantalla, para que el usuario no de ctrl + p si no, solo de click en el boton.
Espero y me puedan decir que debo de usar para investigarlo.

Comment: Haz investigado algo?

Comment: Si y no encuentro ejemplos, pero ahora estoy utilizado esto: <a href="/" target="_blank"></a> Y cuando me abre la página le estoy dando estilo. ya hice unas pruebas y si me imprime él área que deseo. pero me gustaría más poner el botón de imprimir y listo no darle el ctrl + p.

Comment: ya lo pude hacer, en mi html use las clases de bootstrap, que me permiten visualizar contenido en el navegador y esconderlas en la impresion.
En mi controlador use la siguiente funcion: $scope.imprimir = function(){
  window.print();
 }
a mi boton le puse esta funcion y ya me manda directo a la ventana de impresion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lo que se debe usar sería :
ng-app, ng-model, ng-controller, ng-click